# Stanford NLP: Loading the parse model fails

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I've got a problem loading the Parse models from Stanford NLP tools.
I deserialize the model file like i should, but it fails when it comes to the binary grammar part, with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BinaryGrammar.init(BinaryGrammar.java:216)
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BinaryGrammar.readObject(BinaryGrammar.java:203)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
...
```

Did anyone experience similar errors? What could be the cause?

**EDIT:**

Here the code (nothing surprising, just plain deserialization).

```
        ObjectInputStream in;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = aUrl.openStream();

        in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(is)));

        ParserData parserdata = (ParserData) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        return parserdata;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
```

I am not sure about the version i use, as i get the library from a private repository (as i do the model), but i will check which versions are in there.

**EDIT2:**

After checking versions, i found out i used a model from 2011 with a parser version from 2012 (still not exactly sure which versions were used here). Using a newer model file resolved the problem, sorry to bother you.

Comment: Can you show us the code? What version is this? Can you check also if the model file is not corrupted (e.g., comparing with other running versions)?

Comment: Same here: need more information. Most likely a grammar/parser version mismatch?